# Casting as float vs int returning different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Mathematically, these results are similar, I'm just curious about their behavior.  The first version when my local variable is declared as a float, the rounding function stops the decimals displayed at the second decimal. In the second version with the local variable declared as an int the `round` function rounds to two decimal places, and then adds a bunch of zeroes.  Why would the variable type cause the `round` function to behave differently?

```
declare @totalpop float 
set @totalpop = (select count(distinct patid) from members)
select @totalpop
select edutext
,COUNT(*) as educationCounts
,round(100.0*COUNT(*)/@totalpop,2)
from
(
select distinct m.patid, e.eduText
    from members as m
    inner join EducationTable as e on e.eduID = m.education
)x
group by x.eduText
```

--doesn't round to two decimal places

```
declare @totalpop int
set @totalpop = (select count(distinct patid) from members)
select @totalpop
select edutext
,COUNT(*) as educationCounts
,round(100.0*COUNT(*)/@totalpop,2)
from
(
select distinct m.patid, e.eduText
    from members as m
    inner join EducationTable as e on e.eduID = m.education
)x
group by x.eduText
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: +1 to @Jamiec for the epic reference, even out of topic ! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's take a look at the ROUND() function definition :

```
Returns a numeric value, rounded to the specified length or precision.
```

It says ROUNDED to the specified length, not TRUNCATED to the specified length.

Now, using an int and a float yields completely different expression type. You can compare them easily with the following queries ( I switched `COUNT(*)` to 1, and `@totalpop` to 1 also ) :

```
Select sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(int, 1), 'BaseType') BaseType,
       sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(int, 1), 'Precision') Precision,
       sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(int, 1), 'Scale') Scale

Select sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(float, 1.0), 'BaseType') BaseType,
       sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(float, 1.0), 'Precision') Precision,
       sql_variant_property(100.0 * 1 / convert(float, 1.0), 'Scale') Scale
```

This tells us that using an int, the expression gives you a numeric. Using a float, you get a float. According to Microsoft, their ROUND function will return a float when passed a float, and a decimal when passed a numeric.

You can read all about it there : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

At last, you can see that a float get's truncated when the zeros starts, and the numeric never gets truncated until it reach the scale limit :

```
select CONVERT(float, 3.330000),          -- 3.33
       CONVERT(numeric(17, 12), 3.330000) -- 3.330000000000
```